# Need help finding the sum of all numbers in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, addition

I'm trying to find all of the numbers that are multiple of 3 or 5 below 1000. After I get all of the numbers, I would like to add them up.

I was able to figure out how to find the multiples and add them to an array but unable to figure out how to add them together.

Here's my code:

```
var add = [];
var count = 0;

if ( i % 3 == 0 || i %5 == 0) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i ++) {
        add.push(i);
    }
};

function whole () {
    for(var i = 0 ; i <= add.length; i ++) {
        count = count + add[i];
    }
};

whole();
```

Comment: first of all, is the above code inside a function?

Answer (score 2):

The first loop won't ever happen because `i` is `undefined` (i%3 is NaN) at that point.

I think you just need to invert the `for` with the `if`.

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 1000; i ++) {
  if ( i % 3 == 0 || i %5 == 0) {
    add.push(i);
  }
};
```

The assertion that you need to return `count` isn't true. The function is simply going to act on the global `count`.

A cleaner, functionally pure way to do this:

```
function whole(i, count, max){
  if(i > max){
   return count;
 }
 if(i % 3 === 0 || i % 5 === 0){
   return whole(i + 1, count + i, max);
 }
 return whole(i + 1, count, max);
}

whole(0, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the condition inside the loop as well letting the loop run until `i < 1000` because you only want the numbers below 1000.

```
for (var i = 1; i < 1000; i ++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0 || i %5 == 0) {
        add.push(i);
    }
}
```

In the whole function you need to run ntil `i < add.length`or else you will try to add an undefined index to your sum.

```
function whole () {
    for(var i = 0 ; i < add.length; i ++) {
        count = count + add[i];
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better way to sum an array of numbers.

You can use a [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function on your array to get a "reduced" value

```
add.reduce(function(x,y) { return x+y; }, 0);
```

---

For example `((0 + 1) + 2) + 3` will return `6`

```
[1,2,3].reduce(function(x,y) { return x+y; }, 0); //=> 6
```

---

Here's another interesting way to potentially solve the problem with a more functional approach.

> It uses **ES6**, but do not fret. You can easily copy/paste the example into [babeljs.io/repl](http://babeljs.io/repl) to see it run. Babel will also give you the equivalent ES5.

```
// let's say we have an array of 1000 numbers
let ns = new Array(1000);

// fill the array with numbers
for (let i=0, len=ns.length; i<len; i++) {
  ns[i] = i+1;
}

// some reusable functions
let mod     = y => x => x % y;
let eq      = y => x => x === y;
let id      = x => x;
let filter  = f => xs => xs.filter(f);
let reduce  = f => i => xs => xs.reduce(uncurry(f), i);
let comp    = g => f => x => g(f(x));
let compN   = reduce(comp)(id);
let uncurry = f => (x,y) => f(x)(y);

// these are some helpers you could define using the reusable functions
let add = y => x => x + y;
let sum = reduce(add)(0);
let divisibleBy = x => comp(eq(0))(mod(x));

// define your solution as a composition
//   of `sum`, `divisbleBy(5)`, and `divisibleBy(3)`
let solution = compN([
  sum,
  filter(divisibleBy(5)),
  filter(divisibleBy(3))
]);

// output the solution passing in the original `ns` array
console.log(solution(ns));
```

Comment: He doesn't need to return count. count is in the global scope and after calling whole(); he can just read the sum from count.

Comment: @SebastianNette either way, the function shouldn't use a global variable like that.

Comment: Why not? It's a perfectly fine way and often the best way. In this case he won't even need a function though.

Comment: Lol. Global variables are now "the best way" ... What has the world come to ?

Comment: Maybe you didn't program that much in javascript then. There is a whole coding pattern called module pattern which is doing exactly that.

Comment: Right, because that code in the question totally looks like it's leveraging the module pattern. There's no mention of node.js and there's no closure around it. And the module pattern doesn't encourage *global* variables anyway; they're still scoped to a function/module.

Comment: Since when does the module pattern require nodejs? Going by your logic your own answer seems to miss the point of the question. The module pattern is just one of many examples.

Comment: Where's the closure to define his module? He's asking about adding numbers and you think he's aware of the module pattern? -- I said there's no mention of node.js because the only way you could assume he *was* using the module pattern is if he mentioned node.js himself; node.js automatically treats each file as a module.

Comment: Anyway, I don't have time to argue with you. I hope I encouraged you to refresh your javascript knowledge. Have a nice day.

Comment: @SebastianNette lol ok. I'd encourage you to learn what pure and total functions are. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you were close. In your whole function, you need to return count.

```
function whole () {
   for(var i = 0 ; i <= add.length; i ++) {
       count = count + add[i];
   }
   return count;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call reduce without start parameter.

> arr.reduce(callback[, initialValue]): `If no initialValue was provided, then previousValue will be equal to the first value in the array and currentValue will be equal to the second.` [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```
add.reduce(function(x, y) { return x + y; });
```